# Meteor.js - jQuery - fadeOut login error message

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to fadeOut error message that appears when user login attempt fails.
Thought this would work but it doesnt. Any ideas ?

Problem: The message that appears after failed login attempt doesnt get fadeOut()

```
   Template.signin.events({
      "submit #signin-form": function(event, template) {
         event.preventDefault();
         Meteor.loginWithPassword(
            template.find("#signin-username").value,
            template.find("#signin-password").value,
            function(error) {
              if (error) {
                 Session.set('errorMessage', error.message);
                 $('#err').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow'); //   #err is id of error message div
              }else{
                 Session.set('errorMessage', undefined);
                 Router.go('/');
              }
            }
        );
      }
    });
```

Template:

```
<template name="signin">
    <div id="signin-div">
    <center><img id="logo-lg" src="logo.jpg"/></center>
        <div class="container">
        <form id="signin-form" class="form-signin" role="form">
            <div class="signinerr">  
            {{#if errorMessage}}
                <div id="err" class="alert alert-danger  " role="alert">Login failed!</div>
            {{/if}} 
            </div>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Log in to Hive</h2>
            <input id="signin-username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <input id="signin-password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <!--  <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
       -->
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>

        </div>
    </div>
{{>footer}}
</template>
```

SOLUTION: I thought I post it. I used Saimeunt answer for this.

This will display your message

```
    Tracker.afterFlush( function() {
        $('#err').stop(clearQueue=true).fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

    });
```

...and will prevent animation queue build up.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Could you provide a fiddle or codepen that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand how the reactive template engine works to solve this one.

When you set the `Session` variable to the state where it will trigger the insertion of your div error message in the DOM, what you are really doing is just setting a flag, your code flow is not magically jumping to the Meteor internal functions who will be responsible for actually creating the div and inserting it into the DOM.

This is basically why the next line of your code, fading out the div using jquery will silently fail : the div isn't yet in the DOM after all !

Setting the `Session` variable will actually invalidate an internal `Template` computation that will insert your error message *at some point later*.

So what you want to do after setting the `Session` variable is not immediately manipulating the yet to be inserted div, you want to tell the `Tracker` system (the Meteor internal system for tracking reactive changes) to finish its own invalidated computations reruns first, and then only play with the freshly inserted div using `jQuery`.

This is how you do it :

```
Session.set("errorMessage",error.message);
Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
  $('#err').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

More on `Tracker.afterFlush` in the docs : http://docs.meteor.com/#tracker_afterflush

Comment: Thank your for clearing things out. We were all noobs at some point. The only problem I noticed is that error message doesnt show back after next failed login attempt. Anyways, thnaks

UPDATE: $('#err').fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow'); This sort it out  -- the drawback is that when user clicks submit button with wrong credentials 10 times, it will keep animating.

Comment: you can use .stop() or .finish() to to the submit button in the event: In your `Template.signin.events` code with the `submit #signin-form` method, just add `$('#err').stop()`  That should stop the animation upon clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution where we let Meteor do it's job of managing the HTML, using http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

```
{{#if errorMessage}}
  <div class="alert alert-danger animated fadeOut" role="alert">Login failed!</div>
{{/if}}
```

And

```
Session.set('errorMessage', error.message);
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
   Session.set('errorMessage',null);
},2000);
```